# tag input and onChange - Reapeted rendering stop typing (React & Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, input, render

i need to create n input dynmically.
After the first one is typed for the first time I need to create a second one and after some input go inside the third must be rendered e so go on...
my problem is this: every time I type inside a input the flowing of the typing is blocked and you have to click again with the mouse to continue to write on it. I want to write separately and send onChange without the user is interrupted between change input typing.
I hope I was clear.Thank you guys!!

this is a part of my component :

```
const [forms, setForms] = useState([{ id: 0, value: ""}]);
const Extra_tags = (el) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <div style={{display: "flex", alignItems: "center", maxHeight: "3rem"}}>
                    <div>{el.el}</div>
                </div>
                {forms.map((form) => (
                    <div key={form.id}>
                        {form.id}
                        <TextField
                            value={form.value}
                            onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(form.id, e.target.value)}
                                   
                        />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

e these are methods:

```
const replaceDataAtIndex = (index, newData) => {
        const newDataArray = [...forms];
        newDataArray[index] = newData;
        const lastForm = forms[forms.length - 1];
        if (indexPressed && !indexPressed.includes(index) && forms.length < 5) {
            setForms([...forms, { id: lastForm.id + 1, value: ''}]);
        }else{
            setForms(newDataArray);
        }
        setIndexPressed([...indexPressed, index]);
    };


    const handleInputChange = (id, value) => {
        console.log("quihandleforminiziale");
        const newForm = {id: id, value: value}
        replaceDataAtIndex(id, newForm);
        const lastForm = forms[forms.length - 1];
        if (indexPressed && !indexPressed.includes(id) && forms.length < 5) {
            setForms([...forms, { id: lastForm.id + 1, value: ''}]);
        }
        setIndexPressed([...indexPressed, id]);   
    };
```

Comment: It would help to answer easily if you created some sort of code sandbox for this so we can easily debug

Comment: Try using onBlur instead of onChange as the user losses focus the onBlur event can trigger the function

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sorry if I was not clear with my problem.... my problem was I cannot write at the same time on multiple tag input wthout being interrupted from renders ( example cannot write house ... after i try to press h of house i was stopped from a render... My solution is react useForm and ArrayField and watcher ....  there is all there what is was asking

Comment: thank you for the time and sorry for my problem issue